# Landsat8 surface reflectance rescaling pixel

Tags: landsat-8, reflectance, surface

Sorry for this basic question, but I am using Landsat8 images with "surface reflectance" treatment from Landsat8.

I am having some trouble with the data from some bands. Most of pixel are beyond 10k.

According Landsat8, we have a range between -2000 ~16000. 
The valid range from Landsat8 is 0 ~ 10000, but I do not know what to do with the data outside this range

First option: -2000 will be 0
              16000 will be 10000
              And after this we multiply per 0.0001

Second option: lower than 0 will be -9999
               Higher than 10000 will be -9999
               And after this we multiply per 0.0001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the second option. Data under 0 or over 10000 needs to be handled as `NULL` data (saturated cells). In your case, NULL Value is -9999, but if you set those ranges as a value instead of a NULL cell, the value will be multiplied with the scale factor. It depends of the software used